# which antivirus i can install in windows 2000 server?

Tags: anti-virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free antivirus solutions for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows)

Hi friends,

I have a windows 2000 advanced server

5.00.2195

service pack 4 installed in my lan network.

I'm using this as my server in my network.

I was using Norton antivirus 2001 in it as the antivirus.

but its not updating now.

And now i'm trying to use any other antivirus in it.
But i cant install any in it. Nothing is suiting with 2000 server.

can any one say which i can use in it.

I have tried avg, nod32. But nothing worked.

Please help me

Comment: Have you tried looking at the related questions on this site?  such as http://superuser.com/questions/122028/paid-antivirus-solutions-for-windows, or http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows or http://superuser.com/questions/98871/antivirus-program-comparison?

Comment: can u please suggest one

Comment: this is not a site for suggestion. that's what http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for. anyway updating a 10-year-old OS will provide much more protection than installing an old antivirus that supports it